# architecting a bidding system with shared budget

Tags: performance, architecture, distributed-computing

How would you architect for the following requirements for a bidding system:

1. 10 million requests per minute
2. response time of 100ms, of which 60ms is server time, and 40ms is network time
3. There is a budget that decreases with every bid that wins. You want to avoid situations where you bid with no money or submit more bids than you can afford.

Comment: I was asked this question during an interview a while ago. Is there a standard answer to this kind of thing?

Comment: Nope no easy answers, its a test of your knowledge. Depending on your answer they can see what you know.

Comment: How do I go about gaining this knowledge? Are there books and articles that you can recommend? Read all the posts on highscalability.com? :)

Comment: Which technology? Or architecture in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relevant StackOverflow questions:

- [Good Architecture Interview Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816258/good-architecture-interview-questions)
- [System design interview questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323177/system-design-interview-questions)
  (with links to good articles)
- [Best way to prepare for Design and Architecture questions related to big data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916824/best-way-to-prepare-for-design-and-architecture-questions-related-to-big-data)
- [How to design scalable applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907260/how-to-design-scalable-applications) (scalable application sort of your question)

Other tips:

- Read books
- Study hard
- Join architecture forums (linkedin,..ask google)
- Read some more

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to distribute the budget evenly to the different machines. Or perhaps evenly to every 5 machines. Then have them borrow from neighbors if necessary. This way you don't have to worry about all machines communicating transactions to one server all the time. Another good thing is that budget distribution is not time critical.